# In entity framework, how would you populate the data in bridge/linked table having many-many relationship?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have 3 entities created using the code first.

- Books   (ID,    Bookname)
- Readers   (ID,    ReaderName)
- BooksReaders   (Book_ID,   Reader_ID)

now in SEED method I have populated them.

```
  public class BooksDBInitialized: DropCreateDatabaseAlways<BooksDbContext>
    {
        public override void InitializeDatabase(BooksDbContext context)
        {
            context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand(TransactionalBehavior.DoNotEnsureTransaction
                , string.Format("ALTER DATABASE [{0}] SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE", context.Database.Connection.Database));

            base.InitializeDatabase(context);
        }
        protected override void Seed(BooksDbContext BooksDbContext) 
        {
            int i= 1;
            int l= 20000;

            IList<Books> BooksList= new List<Books>();

            while (i<= l)
            {

                BooksList.Add(new News() { BookName= "Book-" + i.ToString() });
                l++;
            }
           
            BooksDbContext.Books.AddRange(BooksList);

            IList<Readers> ReadersList = new List<Readers>();

            ReadersList.Add(new Readers() { Readername=  "Mac" });
            ReadersList.Add(new Readers() { Readername=  "Tony" });
            ReadersList.Add(new Readers() { Readername=  "John" });    
        
            newsDbContext.Tags.AddRange(ReadersList);

            base.Seed(BooksDbContext);
        }
    }
```

Now since I am very new to EF. I want to populate the BooksReaders table which happens to be a bridge table between the two, with each BookID to have at least 1 reader populated against it or could be more but at least one.

I cannot get my head around. Help me on this please.

Note it has to be done using EF and shall be like this.

Comment: Any help would be appreciated

Comment: I had the wrong duplicate, but really, there is a lot of info on this in documentation and in other Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: @GertArnold sorry, where ?

Comment: you can go from readers to books or from books to readers both will populate your bridge table ReadersList.Add(new Readers() { Readername=  "Mac", new List<Book>{new Book(){Name="Book1"}} });